# GSON - Deserialize primitive array

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

Consider this simple Json:

```
{
    "test": [
        0,
        3
    ]
}
```

Now I want to deserialize it in a simple int array so for that I use a custom deserializer:

```
class ArrayDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<int[]> {
    @Override
    public int[] deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("test"), int[].class);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(int[].class, new ArrayDeserializer()).create();
int[] arr = gson.fromJson(json, int[].class);
```

which throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: [0,3]
```

However when I do this:

```
class ArrayDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<int[]> {

    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public int[] deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return gson.fromJson(json.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("test"), int[].class);
    }
}
```

it works and I get the expected output. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's rewrite your `ArrayDeserializer` in to an equivalent form but more expressive

```
class ArrayDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<int[]> {
    @Override
    public int[] deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonArray jsonArray = json.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("test");
        return context.deserialize(jsonArray, int[].class);
    }
}
```

The `JsonDeserializationContext#deserialize` javadoc states

> Invokes default deserialization on the specified object. It should
>   never be invoked on the element received as a parameter of the
>   `JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonElement, Type,
>   JsonDeserializationContext)` method. Doing so will result in an
>   infinite loop since `Gson` will in-turn call the custom deserializer
>   again.

So, even if it had worked, you'd more than likely have a stackoverflow on your hands.

So why didn't it work?

You called (in pseudo-code)

```
deserialize {test:[0,3]} as int[]
// --> Gson finds ArrayDeserializer mapped to int[]
take given JSON as an object (OK), extract 'test' as JSON array (OK)
deserialize [0,3] as int[]
// --> Gson finds ArrayDeserializer mapped to int[]
take given JSON as an object (FAIL)
```

This last time you recurred, the JSON was already in the form of a JSON array but your `ArrayDeserializer` was expecting a JSON object.

In your second attempt

```
return gson.fromJson(json.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("test"), int[].class);
```

you're again extracting the 'test' JSON array and feeding it to a new `Gson` instance on which you haven't registered your `ArrayDeserializer`. In effect, you're invoking

```
new Gson().fromJson("[0,3]", int[].class);
```

which is supported out of the box and will return an `int[]` with the two elements 0 and 3, as expected.

---

There are simpler solutions.

Define a simple POJO type

```
class Pojo {
    private int[] test;
    public int[] getTest() {
        return test;
    }
    public void setTest(int[] test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

and deserialize to it

```
Pojo pojo = new Gson().fromJson(json, Pojo.class);
int[] arr = pojo.getTest();
```

Or

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonArray jsonArray = gson.toJsonTree(json).getAsJsonObject().get("test").getAsJsonArray();
int[] arr = gson.fromJson(jsonArray, int[].class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, looking at your desired version of ArrayDeserializer class:

```
class ArrayDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<int[]> {
    @Override
    public int[] deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("test"), int[].class);
    }
}
```

Inside `deserialize` method you are calling again `deserialize`, so at the second call, you'll not have an array... that is the reason why you have an `IllegalStateException`.

Your method should create an `int[]` array (with the appropriate convertions) and then return it. That's why your second version, with `gson.fromJson` works, because `fromJson` deserializes to `int[]`. Maybe you keep using this to do the converting dirt work.